# Load custom Header class after page loads without jquery

Tags: php, html, css

I have a custom class that creates all of my head html (css/js pages). Within this class, I have a method that adds element specific js and css pages. For example, I have a navigation class that creates a navigation bar which requires a certain javascript page to be linked. For now, I have been calling a method within the header class to add the specific js page to a static variable, then when the `Header::generateHeader` method is called, it adds the correct js/css pages and outputs to html.

My issue is, I need to call `generateHeader` AFTER the other methods on the page are called, or else the static variables aren't set in the Header class.

Any ideas for a work around? I don't think its possible to have generateHeader be called after, because I need the output to be at the top of the page. And I'd like to avoid jquery at all costs, not that I'm against it, I just don't want the entire css to be reliant on jquery.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <?= Header::generateHeader ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= Navigation::generateNavigation ?>
    <?= SomeOtherClass::someOtherMethod ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the code is run from top down you can't have it call the later methods before the former. You could do something like turn on output buffering and capture all the output. Then replace the call to generateHeader with a placeholder. Then at the bottom of the script after everything has run, get the buffer, str_replace the placeholder with the result from generateHeader. Basically what a template system does.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the values to variables, and call them in the order you want.

```
<?php
$nav = Navigation::generateNavigation();
$otherClass = SomeOtherClass::someOtherMethod();
$header = Header::generateHeader();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <?= $header ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= $nav ?>
    <?= $otherClass ?>
  </body>
</html>
```